# What would be the proper German translation for "Orbital Research Station"?

Tags: translation, word-usage, word-choice, german-to-english

Writing a sci-fi, know very little German. What would the proper German translation be for an Orbital Research Station? I'm having trouble figuring out the proper phrasing. Google suggests "Orbitalforschungsstation" but I'm unsure if that's just google ramming words together or that actually makes sense. I've been caught out before!

Answer (score 9):

The ISS is actually a well known orbital research station. The long form of the abbreviation is International Space Station. The literal translation of space station is

> Raumstation

which I suggest. Another possiblilty would be to translate it to

> Weltraum-Forschungsstation (or written as one word) Weltraumforschungsstation.

Comment: Raumstation it is - see https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationale_Raumstation

Comment: @Takkat: Eine Raumstation kann auch anderen Zwecken als der Forschung dienen.

Comment: If it is important that the space station is for research reasons, "Weltraumforschungsstation" is the word to use.

Comment: The OP was asking for a German equivalent of the term "orbital research station", not for (the much wider term) "space station". Downvoted.

Comment: Eine Weltraumforschungsstation muss auch nicht orbital sein, oder? Wobei Station ja irgendwie stationär bedeutet und nicht vagabundierend - praktisch kommen da wohl doch nur orbitale Stationierungen in Frage.

Comment: @userunknown: Sofern nicht von einem geosynchronen Orbit die Rede ist, ist aber auch "orbital" nicht einmal "stationär" in Bezug auf das nächstgelegene Gravitationszentrum. Eine Station, die sich mittels Manövrierdüsen auf halber Strecke zwischen zwei Sternen - oder gar an einer festen Position in Bezug auf ein irgendwie geartetes interstellares Koordinatensystem - hält, ist da im Vergleich schon "stationärer".

Comment: @Pollitzer mag sein, aber da der Begriff üblicherweise für die ISS benutzt wird sollte man erstmal davon ausgehen dass mit “Raumstation” eine Forschungsstation gemeint ist – es sei denn, sie wird in einem militaristischen Kontext erwähnt. “Weltraumforschungsstation” klingt unnötig sperrig und hochgestochen.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Wäre mir auch zu sperrig, mein Favorit ist _»Raumlabor«_.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: 'sollte man erstmal davon ausgehen dass mit “Raumstation” eine Forschungsstation gemeint ist' - diese Annahme ergibt nur unter der Voraussetzung Sinn, dass es praktisch nur hauptsächlich der Forschung dienende Raumstationen gibt, keine (orer nur wenige) für Handel, Verteidigung, Tourismus, Raumschiffbau etc.

Comment: @Pollitzer Eine *Weltraumforschungsstation* könnte auch auf der Erde (z.B. in Bielefeld) stehen, und **am Weltraum** forschen (So wie eine Tierforschungsstation an Tieren forscht).

Comment: @tofro: In diesem Sinne wird das Wort aber nicht verwendet, da würde man eher von _»Weltraumforschungsinstitut«_ sprechen.

Answer (score 8):

*Orbitalforschungsstation* wäre nicht falsch, auch wenn man eher *orbitale Forschungsstation* sagen würde, oder *Forschungssatellit* - bei letzterem jedoch würden die meisten wohl an ein unbemanntes Objekt denken.

Andererseits ist mit orbitaler Forschungsstation eigentlich auch nicht verbindlich gesagt, dass diese bemannt ist. Es könnten dort auch Roboter arbeiten, autonom oder als ferngesteuerte Agenten.

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility:

> [die Weltraumstation](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Weltraumstation)

And maybe better:

> - [das Raumlabor](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raumlabor)
> - [das Weltraumlabor](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Weltraumlabor)

Related: [das Spacelab](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacelab), which is also a [Duden-word](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Spacelab).

Comment: Beside the fact that the orbital placement of the space station (rather than, e.g., a deep space one, or one on the surface of an asteroid) is not reflected in these suggestions: Is a research station automatically a "Labor"? To me, "Labor" seems to imply that experiments are conducted aboard, but that wouldn't necessarily be true for orbital observatories, i.e. space stations that exclusively conduct research by means of telescopes and similar external sensors.

Comment: Accoring to Duden: Raumlabor = **kleine** Raumstation - this also is what we can read from Wikipedia: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raumlabor. *Weltraumstation* and *Weltraumfahrt* today are being replaced by *Raumstation* and *Raumfahrt*.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Experimente gehören für mich schon zu einer Forschungsstation (research station), ansonsten wäre es eine reine Messstation und müsste dann z. B., wie du ja schon selber sagst, space station (Weltraumstation) heißen, was ja alles Mögliche sein kann, auch ein Ersatzteillager oder gar eine JVA.

Comment: @Pollitzer: Eine Art bemanntes Hubble wäre für dich also keine Forschungsstation? Für mich eigentlich schon.

Comment: @Takkat: Ob man _»Raumlabor«_ optimalerweise als _»kleine Raumstation «_ übersetzt, halte ich für fraglich.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Selbstverständlich kann eine Forschungsstation ein Teleskop beinhalten.

Comment: @Pollitzer: Was ist mit Stationen, die Ausschließlich eines oder mehrere Teleskope betreiben?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Das sind für mich Mess- und keine Forschungsstationen.

Comment: @Pollitzer: ich kann auch nur wiedergeben, was Duden und Wikipedia schreiben. Mein Kommentar war als Anregung gedacht, wie Dein Post verbessert werden könnte. Wikipedia-Links sind bei solchen Fragen oft besser, als es der Duden jemals sein könnte.

Comment: @Pollitzer: "Das sind für mich Mess- und keine Forschungsstationen." - ich bin anderer Meinung, aber das erklärt deine Antwort. Danke.

Answer (score 5):

Although there's a direct german translation for the adjective "orbital" (the Duden lists it as "orbital"), it is relatively uncommon. The closest approximation would be "in der Umlaufbahn (oder Erdumlaufbahn)". So "Forschungsstation in der Umlaufbahn" feels pretty close. Compare "arctic research station" which may be written as "Forschungsstation in der Arktis".

Comment: "[the German word *orbital*] is relatively uncommon" - in general, you're right, but the OP is asking about a science fiction context, where that word is not at all uncommon.

Answer (score 1):

To account for both, the research aspect, and the orbital location we may use a rather literal translation:

> *Forschungsstation im Orbit*

This avoids using *orbital* which is uncommon in German, avoids a clumsy compound, and it also avoids doubts that arouse from the alternative terms *[Raumstation](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raumstation)* (space station), or *[Raumlabor](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raumlabor)* as was discussed here in other answers and in comments.

Comment: "This avoids using *orbital* wich is uncommon in German" - as noted in [another comment](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/43264/what-would-be-the-proper-german-translation-for-orbital-research-station/43269#comment105180_43269), that word is not uncommon in German-language science fiction.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Science Fiction hin oder her, ich würde es nicht benutzen: https://www.dwds.de/wb/orbital

Comment: Das zweite Verwendungsbeispiel auf der Seite passt doch perfekt: "Er soll zu einer Laserkanone für Orbitale Kampfstationen weiterentwickelt werden."

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Wobei man sich fragt, wie ein Wörterbuch das in diesem Kontext groß schreiben kann.

Comment: @tofro: In der Tat, der Textabschnitt steht aber aus irgendeinem Grund so im DWDS-Kernkorpus. Dort bzw. in den Zeitungskorpora finden sich aber auch Beispiele mit Kleinschreibung (z.B. "die Option eines orbitalen Endlagers (...), also die Möglichkeit, Atommüll mit Raketen ins All zu schießen"; "wird auf einer Umlaufbahn fliegen, die von der Raumstation aus nicht erreichbar ist und damit „ihre eigene orbitale Infrastruktur“ (DFVLR) benötigt", beide von [hier](https://www.dwds.de/r?corpus=zeit;q=orbital)).